# O que é o (^) no php?

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma comparação de dois números binários verificando em qual índice da direita para esquerda os bits são diferentes. Encontrei um código assim que funciona:

```
strspn(strrev("1111") ^ strrev("1101"), "\0");
```

Esse código me retorna `1`que é o índice do primeiro bit dos números que são diferentes. Porém eu não entendi "bulhufas" do código e nem o que significa isso: **(^)**. Tentei pesquisar no próprio manual e não encontrei. Para tentar descobrir o que é isso, eu fiz isso:

```
var_dump("aaab" ^ "aaac");
```

Só que isso retorna uma "string" de caractere de controle `SOH`.

Então, a minha pergunta se resume em 3 partes:

1. O que é esse sinal (^) e o que ele faz exatamente?
2. Como funciona aquela primeira linha do código?
3. Porque esse retorno em caractere de controle `SOH`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É o operador XOR, como pode ser verificado em mais detalhes através desse link: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Obrigado manowww!